# Nodejs not reading react login form data

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a login system for my application(ReactJs + NodeJs). I have a pretty simple form in react for login. The problem is my nodejs login api is not reading the username and password.

This here is my React form:

```
function Login(props) {
  
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [admin, setAdmin]       = useState()

  const handleLogin = async e =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const admin = {username, password};
    console.log(admin);
    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:8000/api/auth/v1/login",
      admin
    );
    setAdmin(response.data)
    localStorage.setItem('admin', response.data);
    console.log(response.data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="Login">
        <Form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
          <h3>Login</h3>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Username</label>
              <input 
                type="text" 
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="username"  
                required
                name="username"
                onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Password</label>
              <input 
                type="password" 
                className="form-control" 
                placeholder="Enter password" 
                required
                name="password"
                onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>

            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success btn-block">Submit</button>
        </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And my login:

**UPDATE 1**

```
login(app, database) {
        app.post("/api/auth/v1/login", (req, response) => {
            const username = req.body.username;
            const password = req.body.password;
            console.log("before db query");
            database.query(
              "SELECT * FROM admin_cred WHERE username = '?'",
              username,
              (err, results) => {
                console.log("inside db query");
                if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                }
                if (results.length > 0) {
                    if (password == results[0].password) {
                        console.log(username);
                        response.json({ 
                            loggedIn: true, 
                            username: username 
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log("wrong username or password")
                        response.json({
                        loggedIn: false,
                        message: "Wrong username/password combo!",
                    });
                  }
                } else {
                    console.log("user dont exist")
                    response.json({ 
                        loggedIn: false, 
                        message: "User doesn't exist" 
                    });
                }
              }
            );
          });
    }
```

Every time I click on login button I get

**username and password empty**

Can anyone point out where I'm making the mistake?

**N.B: I'm using heroku CLEARDB for Database**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the final statement that worked

```
"SELECT * FROM admin_cred WHERE username = '"+[username]+"'"
```

Answer (score 1):

`POST` parameters go in `request.body`, not `request.params`.

Don't forget to set up the necessary middleware to handle the POST parameters when you first configure your express `app` object.

```
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

And, beware, storing unhashed passwords in your table is a well-known bad idea. Look up password hashing. Please. Because cybercreeps.

Comment: I've already used express.json and urlencoded() and have changed params to body
Thank you